# Why can the body of a lambda expression be composed of only a throws statement?

Tags: java, lambda

I have this code:

```
public class Sample {
  public static void useCallable(Callable<Integer> expression){}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    useCallable(()->{throw new IOException();});
  }
}
```

which compiles and runs fine.

However, shouldn't `Callable<Integer>` take nothing as input and return an Integer?

`()->{throw new IOException();}` doesn't return anything, so why is it a valid `Callable<Integer>` expression?

Comment: [Refer docs before ask questions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call())

Comment: @JudeNiroshan What do the docs say about lambdas without return statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same reason this method compiles:

```
Integer foo() throws Exception {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Which compiles for the same reason as this method:

```
Integer foo() throws Exception {
    if (hasFoo()) {
        return getFoo();
    } else {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

To quote the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7),

> If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

What does "complete normally" mean? According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1) (emphasis mine),

> If all the steps are carried out as described, with no indication of abrupt completion, the statement is said to **complete normally**. However, certain events may prevent a statement from completing normally:
>
> - The `break` (§14.15), `continue` (§14.16), and **`return`** (§14.17) statements cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements that contain them.
> - Evaluation of certain expressions may throw exceptions from the Java Virtual Machine (§15.6). **An explicit `throw`** (§14.18) statement also results in an exception. An exception causes a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements.

In other words, a method with a return type must *either* return or throw. Yours does the latter, so it's valid.

Comment: As an addendum, besides the possibility to complete abruptly, never completing at all also prevents normal completion, so `useCallable(() -> { while(true); });` is valid too.